# Docker Machine can ssh but not scp

Tags: docker, scp, docker-machine

I started to use Docker Machine and I just saw there's a scp command.
Like the documentation said:

`$ docker-machine ssh dev 'echo A file created remotely! >foo.txt'
 $ docker-machine scp dev:/home/docker/foo.txt .`

I did the same by creating a file and then:

`docker-machine scp default:/home/docker/test.txt .`

But I keep facing a status 1.

If I did the reverse, and upload a file to the container, I'm facing lost connection with a status 1. The command:

```
docker-machine scp mongo.tar default:mongo.tar
```

Please assume I'm not an expert with ssh and scp stuff.

Comment: For the second test, you could try and specify a full path? `default:/full/path/to/mongo.tar`

Comment: `docker-machine scp mongo.tar default:/home/docker/mongo.tar` outputs the same result (lost connection with status 1)

Comment: What the docker machine log says? (maybe in `.docker\machine\machines\default\default\Logs\`)

Comment: In VBox.log, nothing special. Last line is: `00:00:36.451922 VMMDev: Guest Log: 00:00:10.010830 vminfo   Error: Unable to connect to system D-Bus (3/3): D-Bus not installed` But I can't see anything relative to scp

Answer (score 7):

if you are running docker-machine from Docker Toolbox on Windows, there is an auto mounted volume where you can access to you host filesystem. By default, the mount point into the VM is /c/Users/ .

Comment: Thank you, this has helped a lot with scp being broken in docker-machine 13.0

Answer (score 2):

This call worked for me:

`scp xxx docker@192.168.99.100:~`

The default password is `tcuser`; alternatively you could use the mount point noted in the answer above.

Comment: Can you please explain why this works? Also, generally posting server IPs and passwords isn't advisable; all we need here is a username with the default (isn't that always the case). Of course, as OP, you have the best ability to understand any risks in posting such information (and I suspect that none of the information posted here was private). Nonetheless, just in case you aren't familiar, this is something to be aware of. I checked, and the specific server does have a firewall filtering all the ports.

Comment: @Greenstick I appreciate your suggestio. I know it's dangerous posting server IPs  and passwords here, So I just post a public password and a inside-net IP, I think it's pretty safe for me and the others.I just want to help somebody else solve this problem, at least it's one of Solution.Despite this, I will be more careful about this.And thanks for your modification and useful advice again.I this worked because it's in docker environment not the docker-machine.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem yesterday and found a workaround (or solution?) today.  This is specific to OS X Sierra and latest Docker and VirtualBox as of this writing.

Going through the docker Getting Started docs (https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/#create-a-cluster), the command:

```
docker-machine scp docker-compose.yml myvm1:~
```

Was immediately returning:

```
Lost connection
Exit Status 1
```

Finally, I tracked it down to my /etc/ssh/ssh_config when I attempted a classic "scp" command without the docker-machine ssh handholding.  The "scp" command returned immediately, complaining about the following incompatible lines:

```
GSSAPIKeyExchange no
GSSAPITrustDNS no
```

I commented those out, which relieved the issue and "docker-machine scp" was able to work as intended.  I did not find this solution posted elsewhere.

My system specifics are pasted below.  Hopefully this helps someone out there.

## OS

OS X Sierra
System Version: macOS 10.12.3 (16D32)
Kernel Version: Darwin 16.4.0

## Docker

Client:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 21:43:09 2017
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 21:43:09 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true

## VirtualBox

Version 5.1.22 r115126

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to copy from host machine to node machine, you may follow this:

sudo docker-machine scp  node1:/home/docker/receive/

It's a very important command to copy docker files from host to manager node. Docker guys please add this command to the docker documentation.